# Facebook app Like bttn header

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like, status

can someone tell me how to replicate the like button and functionality I see in this app page:

```
https://www.facebook.com/illamasqua/app_4949752878
```

ive created an app...and cant determine the users statuc in regards to the liking of a certain page.

Ive added a like button using plugin code...but now need to detect the click of it. Struggling!

```
http://apps.facebook.com/hoo_promo/
```

many thanks
Shaun

Comment: an earlier question got the answer that this is not possible....but then why does the first app above work????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Create an app and set the page tab setings.[image]

2) Place this code in the index.php

```
<?php
 require 'facebook/src/facebook.php';
 $facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $CONF['FB_APP_ID'],
  'secret' => $CONF['FB_APP_SECRET'],
  'cookie' => false,
 ));

 // Get User ID
 $user = $facebook->getUser();
 $signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
 $like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
 if($like_status == 1){ 
 echo 'You liked it';
 }else{  echo 'Please like the page to access'; 
 } ?>
```

modify the config variables.

3) Add the app to fan page using this URL
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=XXXXXXXX&next=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

change the app_id, next varaiables

Thats it.

Comment: thanks for the reply.....couple of issues:

NEXT VAR....what should this be?  when i add a url, i get an error on the app page...'add site url to blah '...i cant see the option to add this url anywhere....sigh....

Comment: next var is your site url or anywhere you want callback when user add this.

Comment: ive added as tab to fanpage...and seems to be working fine. thx. Needed to work out the url....which was like you said.

frustrated the hell out of me this first little facebook app! :)